A closed form description for a particular convex, piecewise linear function
Let $$g(x) = (a_1+b_1(x-s_1))(x \leq s_2)) + \sum_{i=2}^n(a_i+b_i(x-s_i))(x \in [s_i,s_{i+1})), $$
$$\text{and}\quad h(x) = (c_1+d_1(x-t_1))(x \leq t_2 ) + \sum_{i=2}^m(c_i+d_i(x-t_i))(x \in [t_i,t_{i+1}))$$ be convex and monotonically decreasing, piecewise linear functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $s_1 \leq \ldots \leq s_{n+1} = \infty$ and $t_1 \leq \ldots\leq t_{m+1}=\infty$. It is not hard to see that,
$$f(x) = \min_{y \geq 0}\{g(x - y) +  h(y)\},$$
is also a convex and monotonically decreasing, piecewise linear function. However, the parameterization of $f$ in terms of its intercepts, slopes, and breakpoints is less obvious.
In particular, I ask, what are
values $k, e_i, f_i, r_i$ such that
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k(e_i+f_i(x-r_i))(x \in [r_i,r_{i+1})),$$
holds?
Of course, the answer is non-unique. A closed form expression is also not necessary, rather, any solution computable in $\mathcal{O}(n+m)$ time is acceptable.

I am not sure the definitions make sense here. If $s_1 = -\infty$, then what is $b_1 s_1$ in the definition of $g$. Also, as your functions are monotonically decreasing, you need $d_i \le 0$. If $d_m < 0$, then I think you get $f(x) = -\infty$, don't you?

Thank you @gabalz, I have updated the question in response to your comment.
